# How to execute a number of lines using xargs

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, pipe

I have a large sql dump that has 1 insert statement per line. I want to be able to pipe this to xargs so that I can slow down the writes. Basically I want to execute a number of lines, sleep, then continue to execute and so forth.

I current have this:

```
cat file.sql | xargs -n50 -d "\n" sh -c '(echo "$@" | mysql db_name); sleep 10'
```

But the problem is that I believe somewhere in the file, there's a `\n` that's causing sql to break. I'm using `INSERT IGNORE` and this is resulting to missing rows.

I don't want to go through the file and fix the `\n`. Is there a way to use line instead of `\n`?

I've tried:

```
cat file.sql | xargs -L 50 sh -c '(echo "$@" | mysql db_name); sleep 10'
```

but I'm getting:

```
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually just modify the SQL. MySQL has a `SLEEP` function you can select from. The following will inject a 10 second delay every 50 lines... And then just pipe that into the `mysql` command.

```
awk '{print} NR%50==0 {print "SELECT SLEEP(10);"}' file.sql | mysql db_name
```